# How to turn off "moving into" in IOS camera? (Live Photo)

Tags: ios, camera

One of the recent IOS updates introduced a feature which no doubt some like, but I hate it.  I refer to the 2-3 seconds of video showing how the camera moved before I took the picture.

I have absolutely no use for this, and since I do take real videos from time to time, I have no way to automate removing the crap.

Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: Yeah, 'live' photos. I have no idea who thought that 2 seconds of dodgy camera shake would improve the experience.

Comment: I really like the live photo feature.  I mostly use it when someone blinks during a shot.  I can scroll backward or forward to find a good image where nobody is blinking.

Comment: Ah, so there IS a plausible excuse.  Still, having it be the default setting was stupid.  If someone blinks, I can turn it on and try again.

Comment: I've never investigated, but is the video as high quality as the photo? tbh if I want photos I take my camera, I only use the phone for 'snaps' so it's really unimportant...

Comment: @fsb: I retract that concession.  Since "burst" has been available for ages, this new feature is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about the "[Live](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207310)" photos feature. At the top of your camera app screen are the icons for things like the flash and HDR settings. In the middle you should see one that looks like a bunch of concentric yellow circles. Tap it to turn off Live photos.

Comment: Thanks.  It is now OFF.  Unfortunately, I'll probably turn it on accidentally.  And I still have hundreds of little bits of .mov created before I knew it was happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have accidentally turned on "Live Photo". That records 1.5sec before and after the image. You can play the full thing by 3D Touching the image and it also makes quite a nice lock screen wallpaper(as you can 3D touch it).

You can turn this off up the top of the camera app by pressing the circle icon.

Yellow indicates that it is on and white shows that it is off.

Answer (score 0):

Please also note, in addition to the other answers, that your Live Photo can and most likely will turn itself on again. This can be triggered by using the built-in camera in Messages (when sending a picture you take directly from the text message window... as opposed to taking the picture with the Camera app and then sending that, if that makes sense) or using the camera directly from the lock screen (swiping from right to left when iPhone is locked).

If you would like to **keep your Live Photo off**, click Settings > Camera Preserve Settings and make sure Live Photo is selected. The text reads:

> "Preserve the Live Photo setting, rather than automatically reset to Live Photo turned on."

Comment: Apparently that setting works poorly, because the idiocy is on again.